# The proper usage of all () function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

How do you use all() function in python? I read the documents from the website, and i'm still unclear how it is used.

Example:

```
>>> a = '----'
>>> b = '--e'
>>> all(a) is '-'
False
>> all(b) is not '-'
True
>>> all(a) is not '-'
True
>>> all(b) is '-'
False
```

i expected the results to be the opposite results for all examples above.

Say, i want to write an if statement that checks if all char is some_str is a '-'. Returns a print statement "all dashes' if some_str contains all '-'

```
some_str = '-------'
if all(some_str) is '-':
   print("all dashes")
elif all(some_str) is not '-':
   print("not all dashes")
```

The result of the above example is always "not all dashes" even if i add a non "-" into some_str

How can i make the above if and elif statements work?

Comment: Side note: I suggest you do some research on how the python "is" operator works.  It is not the same as "==" (as most new programmers usually assume), so using it as a replacement is likely to give you some odd results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`all` requires an iterable, so let's give it one:

```
>>> all(c=='-' for c in '-------')
True
>>> all(c=='-' for c in '------x')
False
```

`all(...)` will always be either `True` or `False`, never `"-"`, which is why your example can't work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  So, can i assume that the any() operates the same way?